# @PathVariable equivalent for Spring 2.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

I am working on some legacy code running Spring 2.5. I need to use something similar to Spring 3's @PathVariable...anything similar available in Spring 2.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you'll probably get is through [ant-style wildcards in mapping paths](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced). You will then have to parse the path manually in your method to get the variable value, I guess.