# Spring 2.5 MVC parameter URL alternative?

Tags: url, spring-mvc, parameters

I know in Spring MVC you pass parameters via the URL as `www.mywebsite.com?param1=test`

However, is there a way to pass parameters in by saying `www.mywebsite.com/test` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [@PathVariable equivalent for Spring 2.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850286/pathvariable-equivalent-for-spring-2-5)

Answer (score 1):

For Spring 2.5, here is another question with an answer:
[@PathVariable equivalent for Spring 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850286/pathvariable-equivalent-for-spring-2-5)

For Spring 3+, do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{name}")
public ModelAndView someController(@PathVariable("name") String name){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the difference between these 2 methodes to pass 
"**Request** parameters" or "**Path** Variables".

@RequestParam like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/departments/{departmentId}")
  public String findDepatment(@PathVariable String departmentId)
```

Or in the case of using @PathVariable

```
@RequestMapping(value="/departments/{departmentId}")
public String findDepatmentAlternative(@PathVariable("departmentId") String someDepartmentId)
```

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-requestmapping-example